# Conversion of connectome weighted graph to Rips Complex

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Basically, I have a connectome matrix. So, every node has a distance based on a specific measure to other nodes in the graph. Can I convert this to a Rips complex then compute its second Betti number as well as lower Betti numbers?